# synchronizing Microsoft Dynamics GP database to the application

Tags: dynamics-gp

I have integrated our application with Microsoft Dynamic GP. If any of the user in Dynamics GP has updated any customer/vendor/other, then we need to update those data in our application.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could do this, but the three that immediately come to mind are:

1. **Add your own triggers** to the Dynamics GP tables that you're interested in.  Make sure you test them well (so that they don't break GP), and that you script them out, since upgrades to GP might result in (or require) their removal and subsequent re-deployment.
2. **Use Microsoft eConnect** for Dynamics GP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973830.aspx), and leverage its Transaction Requester Service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973839.aspx).  [I'm a Microsoft partner, and I consult on these products, but I'm not otherwise affiliated with Microsoft.]
3. **Use a third-party app like SmartConnect** from eOne Business Solution (http://www.eonesolutions.com.au/content.aspx?page=SmartConnect), which leverages the eConnect runtime, and which provides a toolset that simplifies the creation and management of integrations with Dynamics GP, including real-time integrations.  [I'm not affiliated with eOne - just a fan of SmartConnect.]